# Two ruby models. has_one, and belongs_to. Why have two models at all?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

I'm building an app that currently has two models: User and Income.  Every User has one Income, and one Income only. Each Income must belong to a User.

When a User is created, so is their Income.  There should be no Income creation without a User assigned; and as above each User has one Income and one Income only.

**In this case, why have a separate Income MVC at all**?  So far, I have separated each operation as I understood to be best practice, but I'm now reading that calling Income actions from the User controller is taboo.  Example: creating income if user signup is successful, from the user controller.

What are my limitations by deleting the Income MVC and putting these actions and columns in the User MVC?   I still need to add admin user'ship, as only admins will be able to create, delete and index all incomes and users. Admins will have no income data.

I feel like I'll cut of my nose to spite my face

Only Coding for 3.5 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the reason to have a model is because it relates to a table in the DB. You can have models that are just ruby objects (PORO: Plain Old Ruby Objects). I have done this when I want to create views that are amalgams of other things.

Do you need a separate table? That is the real question. If having Income in the User table does not break normalization([Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)) then go for it. If the only column in Income is `:income` (other than :created_at, :updated_at) then there seems to be no reason to have a separate table. If you want to store information about Income, then keep its table. i.e. where the income comes from, adjustments (longevity, etc.), start date, end date, hourly, etc.

If you keep the table you would want to have relationships defined.

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :income
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :income
```

...

```
def Income < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :user
  dependent: :destroy
```

This way you can accept the attributes for Income in User forms and the User controller can build and update a User's Income. This is quite common in Rails. These relationships give you the ability to do things like:
(assuming the Income table has a `yearly` column)

```
@user.income.yearly.number_to_currency
  =>'$50,000.00'

@user.income = 55,000.00
@user.save

SQL (7.4ms)  UPDATE "incomes" SET "yearly" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "incomes"."id" = 1  [["yearly", "50,000.00"], ["updated_at", Sat, 14 Mar 2015 13:43:37 PDT -07:00]]
```

(75.9ms)  COMMIT
=> true

This is a very common pattern in Rails and does not break MVC.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like I need to read up on my nested attributes.  The income is about 90 columns of data, so a bit of a whale.  I'm continuing to experiment.  I'd upvote you but I don't have enough of a reputation to do even that, sorry!  :-)

Comment: Well it sounds like with 90 columns wide, you would certain keep the Income table. If you accept that the above answers your question you can accept the answer. No need to up-vote.